# SQL WHERE != clause results in no results when the WHERE returns nothing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, where-clause

I have this SQL query:

```
USE thr_clinic
GO
WITH CompleteSchedule AS (
    SELECT  U.ID as UserID, U.Role, U.Surname, U.Clinic, TS.ID as TimeSlotID, TS.TimeSlot
    FROM    Users U
        CROSS JOIN  TimeSlots TS
)
SELECT  CS.*
FROM    CompleteSchedule CS
    LEFT JOIN   Appointments A 
        ON A.MedicalStaffID = CS.UserID 
        AND A.TimeSlot = CS.TimeSlotID 
        AND A.AppDate = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(day, 3, GETDATE()))
WHERE   A.ID is null 
        AND CS.Role != 'Patient' 
        AND CS.Clinic = (SELECT Clinic FROM Users WHERE Users.ID = 1)
        AND CS.UserID != (SELECT StaffID FROM DaysOff WHERE DayOff = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(day, 3, GETDATE())))
ORDER BY    CS.UserID, CS.TimeSlotID
```

However, with the `WHERE` just before the `ORDER BY`, if that returns empty (meaning no one is off on the given date) the overall query returns nothing; but if there is a result (someone off), they won't appear, everyone else will and it works fine.

I assumed if it returned empty then it would show everyone, as *empty* isn't a *userID* it can not show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the subquery used in the where clause presumably might return more than one value you probably shouldn't use `!=` but rather `not in`:

```
AND CS.UserID NOT IN (SELECT StaffID FROM DaysOff WHERE DayOff
```

Comment: Smashing, completely forgot to take into account != wouldn't handle multiple results.

Comment: @Tom, while this is a problem, it is not the problem you were asking about in your question.  Failure to use `NOT IN` would result in a "subquery returned more than 1 value" error, not an unexpected result set.  Tim's answer below is a more correct answer to your specific problem.

Comment: @mwigdahl Using `not in` solves the original problem which was caused by comparing a discreet value with null too though, just saying. So this is a valid solution too, no?

Answer (score 2):

So you wonder why yo get no rows where the sub-query returns `NULL`? Because `NULL` is neither `=` nor `<>` anything else. Use `IS NULL`:

```
AND ((SELECT StaffID FROM DaysOff WHERE DayOff = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(day, 3, GETDATE() 
     IS NULL OR CS.UserID != (SELECT StaffID FROM DaysOff WHERE DayOff = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(day, 3, GETDATE()))))
```